# Unsupported operand types

Tags: entities

hi suddenly i started to get 
Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in E:\localhost\htdocs\drupal\modules\field\field.info.class.inc on line 479

any page i visit just display this error

how to fix this ?

Comment: this is not enough information..  it's probably a module issue, or perhaps something in your template.php file.  you should try to turn off modules to see if it goes away.

Answer (score 4):

The problem here is that in the given file, the line

```
$field['settings'] += field_info_field_settings($field['type']);
```

fails (i.e line 479), because `field_info_field_settings()` doesn't return an array. This shouldn't happen and it is probably caused by a custom or contrib module or by faulty data in your database.

You can try to trace the error down. Open `field.info.class.inc` in a text editor and put the following code directly above the line 479:

```
$field_settings = field_info_field_settings($field['type']);
if (!is_array($field_settings)) {
  print_r($field);
  die();
}
```

Then load a page where you would normally get that error and look at the printed details (I hope there are any). Then ask yourself the following questions:

- For which field are the settings requested?
- Does this field still exists?
- Is it a field declared by a module that you have disabled?

This should help you to trace down the problem.

Remember to remove the debug code!

Comment: Thx, tried that out .. and the error seems to come from "simplead" module

Comment: @Barjas Can you give some more information? Is the module still enabled? Which version? And so on, some details ...

Comment: honestly i didn't do lot of debug, looks like the problem started after i installed the simpleAds 7.x-2.x-dev. so i went and uninstalled it manually (since the admin page was not accessible cause of the error) and the website is working fine now. then i installed the simpleads 7.x-1.x-dev. which caused NO problems :)

Comment: @Barjas ok, fine then, problem solved ;)